# TSQL Money casted as float is rounding the precision

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, currency

I have a database that is storing amounts and being displayed in a gridview.  I have an amount that is input as 3,594,879.59 and when I look in the gridview I am getting 3,594,880.00.

The SQL Money type is the default Money, nothing was done in SQL when creating the table to customize the Money type.  In Linq I am casting the amount to a float?

What is causing this to happen?  It is only happening on big numbers (ex. I put 1.5 in the db and 1.5 shows in the gridview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the destination is a standard 32-bit float, then you are getting exactly what you should.  Try keeping it as money, or changed it to a scaled integer, or a double-precision (64-bit) floating point.

A 32-bit float has six to seven significant figures of precision.  64-bit floats have just under 16 digits of precision.

Comment: Er... no. Sorry, this is wrong. It's not a matter of opinion, it's just plain wrong. Use decimal - not float or double -  for representing money in .NET applications, since it uses base-10 representation and won't cause rounding errors due to base-2 approximations.

Answer (score 2):

Cast the SQL money type to the CLR type decimal. Decimal is a floating-point numeric type that uses a base-10 internal representation and so can represent any decimal number within range without approximation.

It's slower than float, and you're trading range for precision, but for anything involving money, use decimal to avoid approximation errors.

EDIT: As for "why is this happening" - two reasons. Firstly, floating-point numbers use a base-2 internal representation, in which it is impossible to represent some decimal fractions exactly. Secondly, the reason floating-point numbers are called floating-point is that instead of using a fixed precision for the integer part and a fixed precision for the fractional part, they offer a continuous trade-off between magnitude and precision. Numbers where the integral part is relatively small - like 1.5 - allow the majority of the internal representation to be assigned to the fractional part, and so provide much greater accuracy. As the magnitude of the integral part increases, the bits that were previously used for precision are now needed to store the larger integer value and so the accuracy of the fractional part is compromised.

Very, very crudely, it's like having ten digits and you can put the decimal point wherever you like, so for small values, you can represent very accurate fractions:

```
1.0000000123
```

but for larger values, you don't have nearly so much fractional precision available:

```
1234567890.2
```

For details of how this *actually* works, check out the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) standard.